# How to forward declare a C++ class as inheriting from another class?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I know that I can forward declare a class as follows:

```
class Foo;

// ... now I can use Foo*
```

However, can I do something like this:

```
class Bar {
  public:
    virtual void someFunc();
};
// ... somehow forward declare Class Foo as : public Bar here
someFunc(Foo* foo) {
  foo -> someFunc();
}

class Foo: public Bar {
}
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, the compile error is `invalid use of undefined type 'struct Foo'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can forward declare Bar as `class Bar;` and change the signature of `someFunc` to take a `Bar*` as parameter. Since `someFunc()` is a virtual method in the base class, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

After your forward declaration `Foo` becomes an *incomplete type* and it will remain incomplete until you provide the definition of `Foo`.
While the `Foo` is incomplete any attempt to dereference a pointer to `Foo` is ill-formed. So to write

```
foo->someFunc();
```

you need to provide `Foo`'s definition.